# Identify visible stones in the image - Any Approach in OpenCV & Deeplearning

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have samples images of stones present in the images. I need to identify the visible stones only. The approach which I tried is **threshold based filtering and detecting cv2.contours**. Also, I am looking into **[ENet Architecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02147)** for semantic segmentation based deep learning approach. The samples images are below. 
**Example image1:**
[image]
**Example image2:**
[image]

The code which I tried for contour based detection is as below

```
image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_path, img_name2))
# threshold based customization
lower_bound = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper_bound = np.array([250,55,100])

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#masking the image using inRange() function
imagemask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10)) 
plt.imshow(imagemask, cmap="gray")
# erode and diluation to smoothen the edeges
final_mask = cv2.erode(imagemask, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
final_mask = cv2.dilate(imagemask, np.ones((5, 5), dtype=np.uint8))
# find contours based on the mask
contours = cv2.findContours(final_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# draw contours
img_conts = cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), contours[0], -1, (0,255,0), 3)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10)) 
plt.imshow(img_conts, cmap="gray")
```

The sample contours ouput. I know that the thresholds can be tuned for better results here. [image]

But, what I am looking here for the any better approach or solution can work in this heavy environment for detection small particles like stones. Any ideas to solve in better way?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I completely agree. Here, trying to identify only what we able to see

Comment: I could not crop a single one.

Comment: you want to detect every single stone separately? Instance segmentation like MASK R-CNN might work, but you would need a lot a training data and I guess your image quality is too low.

Comment: @Micka, Need to identify the stones which we could able to see properly

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can use the Canny edge detector to detect the rocks in your images:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 103, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (23, 23), 0)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 65, 0)
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, None, iterations=2)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, None, iterations=2)

imgs = [cv2.imread("image1.jpg"), cv2.imread("image2.jpg")]

for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    contours = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.imshow(str(i), img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output for sample images 1 and 2:

[image]

[image]

You can also tweak the parameters using OpenCV trackbars using the code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from random import randint, sample

def process(img, c_t1, c_t2):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 103, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (23, 23), 0)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, c_t1, c_t2)
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, None, iterations=2)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, None, iterations=2)

def show(imgs, win="Image", scale=1):
    imgs = [cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) if len(img.shape) == 2 else img for img in imgs]
    img_concat = np.concatenate(imgs, 1)
    h, w = img_concat.shape[:2]
    cv2.imshow(win, cv2.resize(img_concat, (int(w * scale), int(h * scale))))

d = {"Canny Threshold 1": (65, 500),
     "Canny Threshold 2": (0, 500)}

imgs = [cv2.imread("image1.jpg"), cv2.imread("image2.jpg")]

cv2.namedWindow("Track Bars")
for i in d:
    cv2.createTrackbar(i, "Track Bars", *d[i], id)

while True:
    c_t1, c_t2 = (cv2.getTrackbarPos(i, "Track Bars") for i in d)
    for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
        img_copy = img.copy()
        processed = process(img, c_t1, c_t2)
        contours = cv2.findContours(processed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
        cv2.drawContours(img_copy, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        show([img_copy, processed], str(i))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]
<sub>*(Click image to expand)*</sub>